# using the encoder part of an autoencoder in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, face-recognition, autoencoder

What i want is to get output of encoder (compressed data) to then do a face_recognition on it .
After training this autoencoder i want to use the trained encoder.

so when i try to run the code i get this error:
How can i solve the problem and extract only the trained encoder part of this autoencoder model ?

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_3 to have shape (8, 8, 64) but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that your model output is the `encoded` part, and you are providing the image you will encode as target, which is correct for an autoencoder. What you need to do is to define

```
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

to train it and then use a separate encoded-like model to use the `.predict` method to obtain the reduced input.

Comment: I did it on purpose (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551478/how-to-separately-use-the-encoder-of-an-autoencoder-in-keras) following this link , i want to only use the encoder part thats why i comment my decoder code

Comment: Right, naturally you want to "use" the encoder part only to reduce the input, but you are trying to train the full model first with `autoencoder.fit_generator(...` which is causing the error of the dimensions mismatch. You are saying to the model encode and the target encode is the original image. If you already have trained the full encoder-decoder model then just use `encoder.predict`

Comment: Thanks for reply that's true I thought it was necessary to take only the encoder part. and the decoder part it's not necessary in case if i use only the encoder part.

Comment: I edited my code but when i use encoded.predict it return this error     :  decoded_imgs = encoded.predict(X_test)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'predict'

Comment: Declare it in some other var as a Model just like autoencoder, for example, `encoder_mode = Model(input_img, encoded)`